# nexus 3: get list of all uploaded files to raw repository

Tags: bash, rest, curl, nexus

We are using nexus 3.0
i upload my files with `curl` to raw repository, like in documentation:
https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/raw.html#_uploading_files_to_hosted_raw_repositories

i tried to query with:
`curl -u login:pw https://mynexus/myrepo`
`curl -u login:pw https://mynexus/myrepo/`
but receive only html with errors

How can i query all uploaded files with `curl`?

Answer (score 3):

```
curl 'http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/extdirect' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: */*' --data-binary '{"action":"coreui_Component","method":"readAssets","data":[{"page":1,"start":0,"limit":300,"sort":[{"property":"name","direction":"ASC"}],"filter":[{"property":"repositoryName","value":"repo_raw"}]}],"type":"rpc","tid":15}' --compressed
```

Something like this works

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nexus `REST` API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api):

For example:

```
curl -u admin:admin123 -X GET 'http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/search?repository=maven-central&group=org.osgi'
```